# Anyone know how to start the game?I can do the rest but just start and getting a value from array is my problem

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

Basically this a hangman game that i wanted to do for some reason but right now my main concern is starting it and selecting a random value from the array keyword and display as a ------ in the middle upper area

```js
<script>
var keywords =["Infinity","One","Ten","Winner","Chicken"];
var score,c,d,e
score = 0;

function startGame()
{
    document.getElementById("hangman").value;
}

function find(x)
{
    var found = false;
    for ( i =0; i < selectedKeyword.length; i++)
{
if(selectedKeyword.charAt(i) ==x)
{
    xxxxx
}

if(found)
{
    if(displayKeyword == selectedKeyword)
{
    alert("Well Done!");
    score++;
    xxxxx
}
}
else
{
    fails++;
    if (fails >=6)
    {
        alert("GAME OVER!");
        xxxxxx
    }

    document.getElementById("hangman").value= displayedKeyword;
    document.getElementById("score").value = score;
    document.getElementById("fails").value = fails;
}

function setChartAt (str,index,chr)
{
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return xxxxx;
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="780">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="right">
Score: <input type="text" id="score" size="2" /><br/>
Fails(6 max):<input type="text" id="fails" size="2"/>
</td>
<td colspan="7" align="center">
<input type="text" id="hangman" value=" --- Hangman --- " size="50"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="msg" value="Click Start to get a word." size="50"/>
</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick"startGame()"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" A " onClick="find('A')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" B " onClick="find('B')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" C " onClick="find('C')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" D " onClick="find('D')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" E " onClick="find('E')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" F " onClick="find('F')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" G " onClick="find('G')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" H " onClick="find('H')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" I " onClick="find('I')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" J " onClick="find('J')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" K " onClick="find('K')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" L " onClick="find('L')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" M " onClick="find('M')"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" N " onClick="find('N')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" O " onClick="find('O')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" P " onClick="find('P')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" Q " onClick="find('Q')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" R " onClick="find('R')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" S " onClick="find('S')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" T " onClick="find('T')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" U " onClick="find('U')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" V " onClick="find('V')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" W " onClick="find('W')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" X " onClick="find('X')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" Y " onClick="find('Y')"/>
</td>
<td width="60" align="center">
    <input type="button" value=" Z " onClick="find('Z')"/>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically this a hangman game that i wanted to do for some reason but right now my main concern is starting it and selecting a random value from the array keyword and display as a ------ in the middle upper area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the startGame-function you could randomize the starting value by doing this:

```
var keywordIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length);
selectedKeyword = keywords[keywordIndex];
```

There is probably some more things you have to do to make this game work but I think this answers your question?

Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by choosing the word you want to use as mentioned by Wirde and then showing the "_" and swapping them as the letters are found.

```
let selectedWord = "Infinity";
var lettersFound = [];

function start(){
  lettersFound = [];
  for(i=0; i < selectedWord.length; i++){
    lettersFound.push("");
  }
  render();
}

function find(x){
  for(i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++){
    if(selectedWord.charAt(i).toLowerCase() == x && lettersFound[i] === ""){
      lettersFound[i] = selectedWord.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  render();
}

function render(){
  let shownWord = "";
  for(i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++){
    if(lettersFound[i]===""){
      shownWord +="_ ";
    }else{
      shownWord +=lettersFound[i] + " ";
    }
  }

  let showZone = document.getElementById("msg");
  showZone.value = shownWord;
}
```